# How to convert co-occurrence matrix to sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am starting dealing with sparse matrices so I'm not really proficient on this topic. My problem is, I have a simple coo-occurrences matrix from a word list, just a 2-dimensional co-occurrence matrix word by word counting how many times a word occurs in same context. The matrix is quite sparse since the corpus is not that big. I want to convert it to a sparse matrix to  be able to deal better with it, eventually do some matrix multiplication afterwards. Here what I have done until now (only the first part, the rest is just output format and cleaning data):

```
def matrix(from_corpus):    
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
        heads = set() 
        trans = set()
        for text in corpus:
            d[text[0]][text[1]] += 1
            heads.add(text[0])
            trans.add(text[1])

        return d,heads,trans
```

My idea would be to make a new function:

```
def matrix_to_sparse(d):
    A = sparse.lil_matrix(d)
```

Does this make any sense? This is however not working and somehow I don't the way how get a sparse matrix. Should I better work with numpy arrays? What would be the best way to do this. I want to compare many ways to deal with matrices.

It would be nice if some could put me in the direction.

Comment: [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) should be of use to you. If you're not doing anything with your dictionary, I would say just put it straight in to a matrix.

Comment: Yeap, but I also want to map the co-occurrences by words, would that work if I put my corpus straight in to a matrix? I doubt that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you construct a document-term matrix `A` from a set of documents in SciPy's COO format, which is a good tradeoff between ease of use and efficiency(*):

```
vocabulary = {}  # map terms to column indices
data = []        # values (maybe weights)
row = []         # row (document) indices
col = []         # column (term) indices

for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
    for term in doc:
        # get column index, adding the term to the vocabulary if needed
        j = vocabulary.setdefault(term, len(vocabulary))
        data.append(1)  # uniform weights
        row.append(i)
        col.append(j)

A = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)))
```

Now, to get a cooccurrence matrix:

```
A.T * A
```

(ignore the diagonal, which holds cooccurrences of term with themselves, i.e. squared frequency).

**Alternatively**, use some package that does this kind of thing for you, such as [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org). (I'm a contributor to both projects, so this might not be unbiased advice.)

Comment: Oh yes, I've heard about scikit-learn, but I haven't tried it yet. I guess A.t*A means: transpose A * A, right? Is there any easy way to implement this in python?

Comment: @El_Patrón: `A.T` is Numpy/Scipy syntax for transposition; just copy-paste the expression exactly as I typed it :)

Comment: OK, thank you. I'm having some problems with "extract_terms(doc)", am I missing so module here?

Comment: @El_Patrón: that's a function you should define yourself. If a document, in your representation, is just a list of terms, then you can skip it entirely.

Comment: @larsmans - Hi, could you please point me to the module in scikit-learn that would lets you compute word co-occurrence matrices?